# Spring Integration: iterate through contents of directory only once

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm working with a Spring Integration application which should iterate through the contents of a directory, process the files within it, and then exit.

I've set up the XML below to poll the directory every second, but this isn't quite what I'm after.  How can I change this to read all of the files in the directory, and then have my program exit once the messages have finished flowing through the system?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-2.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd >

    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        directory="inputDir" 
        channel="inputChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"></int:poller>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <!-- more components to read from inputChannel, write to output adapter -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly hacky, I have used this approach in the past and has worked out cleanly.

The approach is to define a `shutdown` queue channel, from your main thread wait on messages to come to this channel and once available to close the application context.

```
<int:channel id="shutdownChannel"><int:queue/></int:channel>
```

In your main thread - :

```
    PollableChannel pollableChannel = applicationContext.getBean("shutdownChannel",PollableChannel.class);
    pollableChannel.receive();
    applicationContext.close();
```

The main code will go past `receive` call only when a message comes into the shutdown channel. Now the question is how to get messages to the shutdown channel.

You can keep some state in the final processor of your file messages, say the time since last time any file was processed, the following could be a strawman:

```
public class FileContentProcessor {
    private long lastProcessedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public void processContent(String content){
        this.lastProcessedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Processed content: " + content);
    }

    public long msSinceLastProcessed(){
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - this.lastProcessedTime;
    }
}
```

Define an inbound channel adapter based on this state:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="fileProcessor" method="msSinceLastProcessed" channel="shutdownFilterChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="3000"/> 
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:filter input-channel="shutdownFilterChannel" output-channel="shutdownChannel" expression="payload>20000"></int:filter>
```

Here I am essentially getting the time since last processed, passing that through a filter which checks if it has been more than 20 seconds since last processing time and passes that message to the shutdown channel.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using a standalone java program then you can probably send messages to an output channel and System.exit when you don't receive messages for a certain interval.

```
 final AbstractApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/*-context.xml");

// initiates poller to poll files
// do your processing and then send to a channel say output ..

PollableChannel output = (PollableChannel) context.getBean("output");
Object msg = null;
while((msg = output.receive(1000)) != null)
   {
        msg = output.receive().getPayload();        
        System.out.println("payload - " + msg);
    }
System.exit(0);
```

Another option could be to send a message to a service activator and then initiate the jvm shutdown.

> Just a note : An EAI pattern is to actually process files and then
>   move to a processed directory.