# Spring integration Automatic Shutdown

Tags: spring-integration

How to create automatic shutdown in spring integration after finish all process for all file? My application use a lot of file as input and use http outbound gateway as last endpoint, so i have http outbound request for each file input ,  and i try to use the last http response from that endpoint as the trigger to shutdown (context.close()) the spring integration. My idea is try to use (System.currentTime()-lastTimeGatewayResponse)>= idleTime as trigger . But i did not find way to get lastTimeGatewayResponse from that gateway.

And afterward I try to folow http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/116366-orderly-shutdown-how-to-know-when-downstream-executor-is-idle. But mybe that not the best aproach, because my application has shutdown while the the process unfinish.

Anyone has experience about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 4.2.x (current version is 4.2.6) you can call `channel.getTimeSinceLastSend()` on the reply channel.

The javadocs says it's in seconds but that's not correct, it's milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually the `lastTimeGatewayResponse` may be fully equivalent to the `timeSinceLastSend` from the `reply-channel` on that gateway.

So, you can specify `nullChannel` as an `output` (`reply-channel`) for your  http outbound gateway and track its `timeSinceLastSend` to perform your shutdown logic.

On the other hand, try to accomplish similar, but more robust behavior, with an `<aggregator>`. You can use `correlationKey` as something static for all your files and trigger shutdown as an input action from the `<aggregator>`. The release strategy may be the count of your input files.

Comment: Can we call "lastTimeGatewayResponse/timeSinceLastSend"  from main class entry point(the place that we call context.xml)? or should call within the endpoint? In your advice is within the <aggregator>, if i do that how to call context.close()? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you give me the example? Thanks. Sorry for a lot of request.

Comment: Well, if it is `main`, typically it stops just after the context refresh, because there is nothing to block that main thread. Anyway you can get access to the `timeSinceLastSend` property getting a `MessageChannel` bean from that context. The problem that you should do that periodically or as a side-event of each file process. Just because you need to have the `idle time` exactly after the last one.

Comment: You can inject some POJO service into the aggregator and perform ` context.close()` from there.

Comment: Thanks Artem, Actualy i understand about aggregator using pojo, the part that i dont understand is how to call context.stop within it, btw is it save if i use System.exit() on my agregator to stop the spring?

Comment: I think so. You can just @Autowired ctx there, if that

Comment: Thanks Artem . I also use tips from Biju Kunjummen : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607283/spring-integration-iterate-through-contents-of-directory-only-once)